# Remove RSS element at certain screen sizes for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, widget, icons

For mobile devices I want to remove my RSS element from my social widget. I tried editing css using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1px){
.a.parent-menu-item.icon-rss {
    display:none;
}                           

@media screen and (max-width: 1px){
    .li.parent-menu-item.icon-rss {
        display:none;
}
```

but it didn't work. I am using the Genesis Framwork and the tru Chilid Theme http://boasish.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the element `.parent-menu-item.icon-rss` is a child of the `li` element. You therefore need to use the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) (a space), in order to select it - (`li .parent-menu-item.icon-rss`).

In addition, you have a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue. Just increase the specificity of the selector.

The following will work, just place it inside the media query.

```
#menu-social li .parent-menu-item.icon-rss {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. How do I get rid of the grey border where the rss icon used to be for the mobile device?

Comment: @k65 Assuming there aren't any other icons, you could simply use `.social_menu { display: none; }`.

Comment: I just tried that and it works, but when I do that it displays a double line for some reason.

Comment: @k65 From what I can see, you set `display: none` on `#menu-social`, not `.social_menu `.

Comment: If I apply it to `.social_menu` it doesn't show up when I look at the tablet or desktop. I'm looking to have the rss icon stay hidden along with the grey lines for the mobile device. For the tablet and desktop I want it to come back out.